# How to add custom animation in CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Tags: android, animation, material-design

In [CollapsingToolbarLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html), child content can set animation when expend or collapse as below :

```
app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
```

But there is only three default animation "**none**", "**pin**" and "**parallax**".

I want to change sliding up default animation to sliding down animation in "parallax" mode. How can i add custom animation or customize existing animation ?